# Passing django variable to slide function in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I know that Django template allow this structure

```
  {% for i in paginator.page_range|slice:":10" %}
```

It means just 10 element from paginator.page_range list.

But how can instead passing 10, want to passing a variable, like this:

```
  {% for i in paginator.page_range|slice:":page_obj.number" %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `slice:":{{page_obj.number}}"`, the `{{}}` is the method to call a variable inside django template.